# SQL Failover Cluster Management -- dealing with the "cluster network name is not online"

Tags: sql-server, cluster, failover

Viewing a failover configuration in the SQL Failover Cluster Management tool, I can see via a succinct warning message that "The cluster network name is not online".
Everything about the cluster checks out though. What can I do to debug this?

I don't have Active Directory setup on the same machine. Some point to this as a potential issue, but in my case, it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the cluster manager it says that the network name is down, or are you looking at the errors and warnings section?  If the errors and warnings section that error might be old from the last failover or something.